# Doing work in Android Firebase Database transaction's background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is my understanding that the Firebase Realtime Database Transaction.Handler doTransaction method does not run in the main UI thread (see [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler.html#doTransaction(com.google.firebase.database.MutableData))).

Is it acceptable to use this thread inside of doTransaction to do some work that will take a few seconds to complete?

```
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            SomeClass p = mutableData.getValue(SomeClass.class);

            //-- do something here that will take a few seconds
            someLongTask(p);

            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
}
```

By "acceptable", I mean is the only impact the responsiveness of my other Firebase database calls?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think yes we could do it as doTranscation is background thread so we could do process which won't be related to UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transaction handler is indeed executed on the Firebase Database SDK's run loop. Performing a long operation will stall all other Firebase Database operations (you won't get any events, writes won't get sent to the backend, etc.) until your transaction handler code has finished and the run loop can catch up.

This will basically affect performance, but won't cause any other issues. So in that sense, it is "acceptable."

In general though, it's not recommended to perform long operations from within a transaction handler. It's important to understand that the transaction handler will often run multiple times before it succeeds. So you typically don't want to perform any operation with side-effects (write to a file or SQL database, etc.) since those side-effects will occur an unknown number of times.

Oftentimes, you can rework your logic so that you do the long expensive operation before starting the transaction, but it depends on the use case.

Comment: Thanks @Michael.  This does present a problem when read-modify-write atomicity is required in a transaction, even in the case when the modification may be a relatively long task--and in this case having the read-modify-write atomic operation block neither the main thread or the Firebase thread would be a valuable feature.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of long operation are you expecting to perform? I've generally only seen people use transactions to implement simple business logic type tasks.

Comment: Good question Michael, because I want to understand if my approach is wrong. In my transaction, based on reading a few fields of the object, I have to make some complex calculations (that will require probably a few seconds computation time) that must be off of the main thread, then based off of these calculations, update some of the object's fields, then write the object back to Firebase.  It's a classic read-modify-write transaction atomicity requirement I believe, except my modification is a bit computationally lengthy.  Btw, love Firebase.

Comment: Glad you're loving Firebase!  I'm still curious what sort of "computationally lengthy" operation you're doing. :-)  In some cases a work queue approach may be preferable (so rather than do the work inside the transaction, you use a transaction to "claim" the item and then go off and do your work and update the item when it's done).  Alternatively, you could read the data (without a transaction), do your calculation, then do a transaction to update the data, but just abort and restart it if the data changed since you read it previously.  Good luck!

Comment: Two great suggestions, but how do I do the first?  How can I claim an item with a transaction without returning the item at the end of the transaction inside the same thread, or aborting? doTransaction has to return a Transaction.Result.  It doesn't seem possible to keep a claim on the item after doTransaction has completed.